# How to add lights to make a scaned model looks real using AR.js

Tags: javascript, ar.js

I am new to AR.js and want to make a very simple demo with AR.j. I get a 3d scanning model from [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/chukkah-boot-b2c46d02f8064701b8e2ebb181ac0f1c)，and put it into AR.js.
I tried `light="type: point" intensity: 5.1`, but the light doesn't looks like the model on sketchfab. When I tried with `light="type: ambient"`, the whole model is black.

```html
<a-entity id="point_light_1" light="type: point; intensity: 5.1;" position="0 0 0"></a-entity>
```

Here is the [example from sketchfab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uLXI.jpg) and [what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlHRi.jpg). How could I get the same render effect like sketchfab shows?

Comment: I checked the [AR.js documentation](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/README.md), and they advertise [a chatroom for questions](https://gitter.im/AR-js/Lobby). You might get better answers from there.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A-frame Document would help you.
https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/light.html#sidebar

The effect of point light change according to the distance from materials. The closer the light bulb gets to an object, the greater the object is lit.Try to set the position of light nearer.

> when i tried with light="type: ambient" whole model is black.

Maybe the model is in the shadowed area.